# How to insert data in database, without inserting duplicates? (vb.net)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I've been searching on the net, and this query should work:

```
INSERT INTO Groep(Naam) SELECT ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Groep Where Naam=?)
```

but it doesn't.. I get an `OleDbException`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'

Comment: **WHAT** database system (and which version)?

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table? Your error message doesn't seem right for the statement you sent. ALso do you have other fields that require values?

Comment: it's ok now, don't know why but it works :) thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName) SELECT '" + value + "' WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ColumnName from TableName WHERE Name = '" + value + "')";
```

Followed by an ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Sorry, I thought you use MySQL Server. I've edited my answers above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that i work with OleDbParameters?
thanks for your help though

Comment: Can you put your code here and the error? So I can get more details of this.

Comment: it's ok now, don't know why but it works :) thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Database is SQL Server ...

### Approach  #1

**Create the Unique key**

`Alter Table TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName PRIMARY KEY (ColumnName)`

---

### Approach  #2

```
If Not Exists(Select PrimaryKey From TableName Where ColumnName = 'Value')
Begin
    Insert Into TableName(Columns....)
    Values(......)
End
```

---

### Approach #3

```
Declare @Var int
select @Var = column1 from TableName Where Column2 = 'Value'
if(@Var is null)
Begin
    Insert Into TableName(Columns....)
    Values(......)
End
```

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server 2008.
My Table "Group" has only 2 columns: "Id" (PK) and "Name"
The first 2 approaches don't work, and i don't completely understand approach #3, do you mean that i have to check if the data is already in the database (in vb.net code) and then add it if it's not in it?
thx for your help so far!

Comment: You have a call a `Stored Procedure`. Approcah #3 is checking the record existence. If it is `Null` record should be inserted.